# Referring to an id from url on a php page

Tags: php, html

I have a page /home/practice.php . On the page, i have elements with assigned id's. I want to refer to the elements . For example, practice.php/#footer , but all the content from the page disappears and i get a blank page . Even if i just put a slash, i.e practice.php/ , nothing shows up on the page.

Comment: Be more precise while asking question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This entirely depends on how you've set your page up, but just as with any HTML page you should be able to refer to:

```
page.php#anchor
```

Where `anchor` refers to an id within the page.

Note the lack of `/` before the `#`

Answer (score 0):

Your file is `practice.php`. Placing a `/` at the end will make your browser treat `practice.php` as a folder instead. If you want to use `#footer` in your URL, simply use `practice.php#footer`.